# image src attribute modifies my url

Tags: php, url, dom, simple-html-dom, src

Mysql database has a column containing urls base64_encoded

When I echo the following:

```
$im_dec = base64_decode($row['image']);
echo $im_dec;
```

I obtain the desired URL:
https://www.ft.com/__origami/service/image/v2/images/raw/http%3A%2F%2Fprod-upp-image-read.ft.com%2F1263ad72-2d9a-11e7-9555-23ef563ecf9a?source=next&fit=scale-down&compression=best&width=210 (5kB)

Then I use this URL to be the src of my img:

```
$newImage = $dom->createElement('img');
$newImage->setAttribute("src", $im_dec);
$newImage->setAttribute("class", "articleImage");
$newTitle->appendChild($newImage);
```

And when I check the src attribute in my html document, I see a modified url where `&` is replaced by `&amp;` and `=` by `&#x3D`;

Of course the image is not displayed because of this...

I don't know how to avoid it. I tried many things but I thought base64 encoding would work... Help please!

Comment: `&amp;` is how one is supposed to insert a literal ampersand into HTML.

Comment: Why would you store normal URLs base64 encoded in the first place? That makes little sense.

Comment: because I scrap the url and I don't want the url to be modified in any way

Comment: the question is why $im_dec is different when I echo it and when I put it as src

Comment: You can read about [URL Encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) so you'll understand what is happening to your img src.

Comment: you're not answering the question.

Comment: `DOM` automatically handles encoding of special characters. You don't have to avoid it

Comment: no! That is the problem, my image is not displayed: the special characters are not encoded!